# How to dispatch request to some view depending on http method?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have Post django model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
```

Serializers:

```
class PostListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'title')

class PostDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

Views:

```
class PostListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer = PostListSerializer

class CreatePostView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer = PostDetailSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
```

Endpoint is /api/posts/

How to dispatch request to PostListView if HTTP Method is GET and to CreatePostView if HTTP Method is POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't, instead of writing `permission_classes` and `serializer` use the `get_serializer_class` and `get_permissions` methods

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.request.method == 'GET':
        return PostListSerializer
    return PostDetailSerializer

def get_permissions(self):
    if self.request.method == 'GET':
        return [IsAuthenticated()]
    return []
```

alternatively, consider if you're expecting too much for the single endpoint